# Content part showing in admin

Tags: orchardcms

I have a custom content part, and I added it in a content item. it works fine, but there is a little problem in content items list on admin: the content part is appearing on it.

here is an image of my problem: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/2b68.png/

Answer (score 2):

In the Placement.info in your module, add the following line:

```
<Match DisplayType="SummaryAdmin">
    <Place Parts_MyPart="-"/>
</Match>
```